# Firebase Dynamic Link - Unshorten the link

Tags: flutter, firebase-dynamic-links

I have a firebase shortened dynamic links.

```
https://mydomain.page.link/EAAP
```

How can i un shorten it?

Comment: If you mean programmatically, it depends on the method you are creating it, API or Package?
If not just open it in a browser!

Comment: @Hooshyar am creating it programatically in flutter using the dynamic link package. In a particular use case i want to un shorten the link to view the link.

Comment: updates about this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the function:

```
var resuslts = await FirebaseDynamicLinks.instance.getDynamicLink(Uri.parse(url));
```

Then you can access the unsorten link:

```
results.link
```